# Initialize String Assembly

Tags: string, assembly, initialization, gnu-assembler

In i386 I'm trying to initialize a string in data.  This is stupid, but I can't get it to work.

```
sentence:
.char 'h',0
```

says `.char` is an illegal pseudo op.  Clearly I'm not doing it right, though

```
sentence: db 'h',0
```

gives nothing either.

Comment: What assembler are you using? They each have their own syntax. All of them have manuals online, so you don't have to guess. ;) And what does *gives nothing either* mean?

Comment: I just meant it didn't work.  So if I use gcc, I'd go to the gcc manual for .data?

Comment: *It didn't work* is quite vague. Do you mean error message? Or it didn't yield expected results? If you're using `gcc`, then you're using `gas` (which is what `gcc` calls). So look up `gas x86 syntax`.

Comment: Using the http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Data_Transfer and putting fmtStr1: db "In thread %d with ID: %02x", 0x0A, 0 as outlined returns "no such instruction db".

Comment: That link has examples of syntax from more than one assembler. It's a generic x86 Wiki article. I googled "gas x86 assembly syntax" and got this as this as the first hit: [X86 Assembly / GAS Syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax)

Answer (score 1):

As *lurker* said, each assembler has its own syntax. `db` is used by `nasm`, for example. `gas` provides `.byte`, `.string`, `.asciz` and a bunch of other directives. See the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Pseudo-Ops.html). Your code could look like:

```
sentence: .string "h"
```